# How to move elements when they don't fit on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want to reorder elements similar to `flex-wrap: wrap`, but I want to reorder the elements. A good example would be Youtube. Go onto any Youtube video [(like this one)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYWlJfwLKPE) on a non-mobile device. After shrinking the page, the recommended videos that were on the right side go between the description and the comment section. If they only used flex wrap, the recommended videos would go below the comment section. How would I do a similar thing?

I assume you would need some javascript, but I'm unsure as to how I would approach this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `display: flex`, there's the `order` parameter for the flex-items (i.e. the *children* of the flex-container), with which you can define any order you want, also within a wrapped flex container. example:  `order: 3;` on a flex item that should be third in order.

Comment: The problem is, the whole left side (comment section, description, video title) is all in one div with id="primary" (you can find it yourself if you inspect element on a youtube video). The recommended videos are all in another div with id="secondary". Even if I did what you said and added that to the parent element of id="primary" and id="secondary", I would still only be able to put one on top of the other or vice versa. Sorry if that's confusing, if you have any questions please ask.

Comment: On youtube, the mobile version / smaller screen apparently has a completely different HTML structure - the recommendations are *inside*  the "primary"  element on smaller screens. I don't know how that is done (javascript would be first choice), but that's definitely a bit more than reordering.

Comment: yeah exactly. I'm asking how I would sense whether the element overflows off the screen, and then reorder the page when that happens in javascript.